# Arrange characters in textbox vertically stacked in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I am working on crystal report and confused about how can I arrange text within text object vertically stacked i.e. if I have "Hello" as value, then it should displayed as 'H', then 'e' below 'H', then 'l' below 'e' and so on.
Please let me if anybody is having solution for same.

Answer (score 0):

here is your answer

```
Mid ("Hello",1,1)&ChrW (13)&Mid ("Hello",2,1)&ChrW (13)&Mid ("Hello",3,1)&ChrW (13)&Mid ("Hello",4,1)&ChrW (13)&Mid ("Hello",5,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click the field, select `Format Field...`, then `Common` tab, then `Text Rotation` 90 degrees.